# Can I convert 1 dimensional array of String to 1 dimensional array of Datacolumn?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have grouped a column using linq query and selected an array of string of values from column. Now what I want is to add all the names I have in that array get added to a new Datatable variable which I have created. It's a blank Datatable. So I am using `Datatable.columns.addrange` method. This method requires an array of `datacolumn`. Is it possible to convert an array of string to an array of datacolumn and add the values in the array of string as columns in my blank Datatable?
Thank you for your time

Comment: `Datatable.Columns.AddRange` means you want to add multiple columns. you need to use another method to create/add a single column. check for `Datatable.Columns.Add` method

Comment: after adding the column you need to add rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might just be easier/more readable to do:

```
foreach(string s in stringarray)
    datatable.Columns.Add(s);
```

But sure you can try:

```
datatable.Columns.AddRange(
  stringarray.Select(s=>new DataColumn(s)).ToArray()
);
```

The problem with this latter method is that it's longer to write, less readable and less efficient so it's kinda lose-lose-lose. The problem with both these methods is that you don't get to specify the Type of the column, unless you're going to inspect the name and eg make any name ending in "Time" a datetime etc.

The best way to use datatable a is with a strongly typed dataset added to the project and the datatables themselves designed in design time, with column types, constraints, relations, expressions etc

In vb.net it would be something like:

```
DT2.Columns.AddRange(gg.Select(Function(r) new DataColumn(CStr(r("Plant")))).ToArray())
```

Which is even more of an unreadable abomination than:

```
For Each r as Thing in gg
  DT2.Columns.Add(CStr(r("Plant")))
```

So we finally get to the point where you're giving us the actual problem: You want to group on Plant, apply some aggregation to another column, and you want to pivot it so your rows become columns. It'll be something like this:

```
    'generate a datatable with dummy data
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Plant")
    dt.Columns.Add("SumMe")
    dt.Rows.Add("Rose", 1)
    dt.Rows.Add("Rose", 2)
    dt.Rows.Add("Tulip", 3)


    Dim groups = dt.AsEnumerable() _
                  .GroupBy(Function(r) New With {Key .Plant = CStr(r("Plant"))}) _
                  .Select(Function(grp) New With {Key grp.Key.Plant, .SumOf = grp.Sum(Function(ro) CInt(ro("SumMe")))})

    'for results
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable()
    dt2.Columns.Add("x")
    dt2.Rows.Add("x")

    For Each group In groups
        dt2.Columns.Add(group.Plant)
        dt2.Rows(0)(group.Plant) = group.SumOf
    Next group
```

I've gone the foreach route; if you're desperate to use AddRange despite the lose-lose-lose caveats earlier mentioned (and it'll get even more complicated this time round because you'll have to turn the grouping into an array and add the columns then foreach it in some form to stash the values in the result dt) I'll leave it as an exercise for you :)

[image]

Comment: hello @Caius thank you for your time and good answer but im getting an error stating the expression does not produce value this is the code im using **Select DT2.Columns.AddRange((gg.Select(Function(r) cstr(r("Plant")) ).toarray).select(Function(a) new datacolumn(a)).toarray)**

Comment: @Vickydas, show your code in the question, and what kind of error you get and you will get correct answer much quicker.

Comment: Judging by the mixed case and lack of strictness around bracket use I'm assuming you're using vb. I don't think the code I wrote has been accurately converted; I only have 1 select, you have 3. Try `DT2.Columns.AddRange(gg.Select(Function(r) new DataColumn(CStr(r("Plant")))).ToArray())`. I might have missed a bracket (but I have said all along that doing it this way is hard to read and hard to understand - and it's kinda been proven now by the fail in converting it to vb. seriously recommend the simpler foreach approach

Comment: Sorry @CaiusJard copied incomplete code that confused u the full code is like this**From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Group By x=New With {key .idd=roww.Item("Col1"),key .iddd=roww.Item("Plant")} Into gg = Group Select DT2.Columns.AddRange((gg.Select(Function(r) cstr(r("Plant")) ).toarray).select(Function(a) new datacolumn(a)).toarray)** and yes i totally understand the cons of this method and ill use for each but still i want to learn it thank you for helping

Comment: Are you aiming to  pivot a datatable?

Comment: You can't select the result of AddRange; it produces no value so there is nothing to select. I also think pursuing this method will come unstuck at some point when two different groups have the same value; you cannot have DataColumn with the same name. It would be simpler to select the distinct values from the plant column and use that as your string array per my code in the post (I can't see the point in performing the grouping operation)

Comment: hello @CaiusJard i am not aiming to pivot it!!  the **plant** Column has different values and repeatitive values so what i want to do i take the distinct name and create a columns for these value also im grouping the column is want sum of the third column after the plant as i said earlier it contains repetitive values

Comment: Well.. You *are* pivoting because you're taking 1 column of N rows, and turning it into 1 row of N columns.. I'll add another edit, but you should understand, going forward, that this is NOT what SO is all about - you don't ask one question, then change it to another, then a third.. and keep moving the goalposts; it just annoys people who are giving up their free time to help you at no cost

Comment: hello @CaiusJard i did it using for each the sole purpose of using add range was to do all the stuff in just a single query.....but ill still try to do using add range later if i want to some challenging stuff that day  :) thank you for your help

Comment: No problems! Worth noting that sometimes you can spend a long time working out some "perfect" but torturously complex LINQ thing, you get it working .. but then every time you look at it in the future you think "how the heck does this work?!" - I've rewritten "clever" code before now because it was just too difficult to understand quickly when revisited months later

Comment: True that @CaiusJard ill keep this in mind......Thank you for your help